# Identity claims are dropped

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

My problem is that while identity claims are correctly present in identity token on initial sign-in, they are absent in the identity token on token refresh.

I (still) use IdentityServer4 and use AspNet core to sign in my users and add some claims:

```cs
var issuer = new IdentityServerUser(signInData.SubString) {
   AdditionalClaims = additionalLocalClaims
};
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(issuer);
```

This results in a proper identity token with the expected claims.

However, these claims are no longer present in the identity token that my client receives on token-refresh.

To investigate:

- I injected a custom `IClaimsTransformation` class. When I set a breakpoint in `TransformAsync` I see that the `principal.Identity.Claims` contains all expected claims.
- I injected a custom profile services (which inherits from `DefaultProfileService`). When I set a breakpoint in `GetProfileDataAsync` the claims are no longer present in `contect.Subject.Claims`

Can anyone explain how the claims identity that is passed to the profile service of IdentityServer4 is constructed and why it does not pick up the claims that are already present in the claims identity that is passed to the claims transformer class of Asp.Net Authentication?

Comment: Hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62571648/identityserver-additionalclaims-not-included-after-login) can give you some help

Comment: Thanks @XinranShen. However, the point is that the claims are present. I guess they are in the cookie. When I set a breakpoint in TransformAsync I can see them. Later (but during the same backend invocation), they seem to be removed because when I set a breakpoint in GetProfileDataAsync, the same identity (with the same sub claim) no longer has these claims.